# Lua: как присвоить переменной значение, а не ссылку, другой переменной?

Tags: lua

Существует таблица. Другой таблице необходимо присвоить значение этой таблицы. Оператор **=** просто делает из нее ссылку на ту таблицу, и, при обновлении последней, изменяется и первоначальная. Существует ли способ исправить это не используя оператор **for**, чтобы перебирать ключ-значения первой таблицы и записывать во вторую?

Comment: Вот [тут](http://lua-users.org/wiki/CopyTable) разные методы приведены.

Comment: Таблицы - не единственное больное место lua, в котором приходится использовать костыли. Лично я использую lume (https://github.com/rxi/lume) это такой набор функций на все случаи жизни, которые почему-то не реализованы нативно.

Answer (score 5):

Есть причина, по которой нет встроенной функции копирования таблицы. Дело в том, что таблица в Lua -- это очень сложный объект. Совсем не очевидно, что должно получиться в результате копирования таблицы. Должны ли быть перенесены метатаблицы? А если там запрет на чтение по ключам? А если у нас наследование метатаблиц? А если есть таблицы в ключах и значениях копируемой таблицы, то их тоже нужно копировать или оставлять ссылки на оригинальные объекты?

В каждом конкретном случае можно написать свою функцию копирования. Например, если у вас таблица-список без метатаблиц и прочего, то можно действительно обойтись без `for k, v in pairs`

```
function table.clone(org)
  return {table.unpack(org)}
end
```

Если индексы в таблице не являются последовательными натуральными числами, то есть это не таблица-список, мы уже вынуждены перебирать пары ключ-значение:

```
function table_copy(orig)
    local copy = {}
    for orig_key, orig_value in pairs(orig) do
       copy[orig_key] = orig_value
    end
    return copy
end
```

А если у таблицы есть нужная нам метатаблица, то копировать нужно и её:

```
function table_copy(orig)
    local copy = {}
    for orig_key, orig_value in pairs(orig) do
       copy[orig_key] = orig_value
    end
    setmetatable(copy, table_copy(getmetatable(orig)))
    return copy
end
```

И чем больше свойств таблиц мы хотим учесть при копировании, тем сложнее будет алгоритм. Самое сложное, что мне попалось на глаза, -- это функция копирования, описанная тут [Non-recursive Deep Copy](https://gist.github.com/Deco/3985043).

По вопросу копирования таблиц написана отдельная статья на [lua-users.org](http://lua-users.org/wiki/CopyTable).

И ещё один обзор способов копирования таблиц [How to deep copy Lua values](https://gist.github.com/tylerneylon/81333721109155b2d244).

Comment: Учитывая сложность описанных вами функций, проще сделать функцию которая будет создавать и возвращать таблицу, а не копировать созданную.

Comment: @stdio.h все описанные выше функции создают новую таблицу, копируют в неё нужную часть данных оригинальной таблицы и возвращают ссылку на эту новую таблицу. За вами лишь выбор, что именно нужно скопировать в новую таблицу.